# Proof verification: open and closed sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Task: Let $F$ and $G$ be sub-sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

$F=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\in[0,10]$ and $y\geq \frac{1}{1+x^2}\}$, and $G=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|y>\frac{1}{1+x^2}\}$.

(a) Show that $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

(b) show that $G$ is a opened set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

---

For (a) I use the fact that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. Here is what I've tried for (a):

Let $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ be a sequence in $F$.

then we have $0 \leq x_n \leq10$, and $y_n \geq\frac{1}{1+x^2_n}$.

Suppose $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$ both in $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore we have the inequalities: $$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\leq10$$ and $$\lim_{y\to\infty} y_n\geq\frac{1}{1+(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)^2}$$

$\implies$ $0 \leq x \leq10$, and $y \geq\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

$\implies$ $(x,y)\in F$

Therefore $F$ contains all of it's limit points, and we conclude F is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Here is what I've tried for (b):

Given the definition of G we have $G^c=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}\}$. From (a) we know that $G^c$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is closed and therefore $(G^c)^c=G$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: any posts regarding whether It "looks just fine" would be appreciated as well as feedback to mistakes I might have made

Comment: It looks good; you had a few typos so I suggested an edit, otherwise it is OK.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind telling me where the typos are? I can't find them myself. Then I can close this post for the archive in case nobody else finds an error (in a few hours).

Comment: You have $x \rightarrow x$ (should be $x_n \rightarrow x$). You have $0 \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \ge 10$ (should be $\le 10$). You have $y \ge \frac {1}{1+x^2_n} $ (should be $y \ge \frac {1}{1+x^2} $).

Comment: A bit simpler solution would use that the preimage of an open/closed set by a continous function is also open/closed. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x,y) = (1+x^2)y$ for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\pi_x : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as $\pi_x(x,y) = x$ for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Both are continuous functions.

We have:

$$F = \pi_x^{-1}([0,10]) \,\cap  f^{-1}([1,+\infty\rangle)$$

so $F$ is closed as an intersection of two closed sets.

Similarly, $G$ is open:
$$G = f^{-1}(\langle 1, +\infty\rangle)$$

Comment: @mechanodroid Using that method, wouldn't you have to argue that the functions are continuous first?

Comment: @user505156 Yes. It could be proven easily by first verifying directly that the projections $\pi_x$ and $\pi_y$ are continuous, and then using that the sum/product/composition of continuous functions is also continuous to prove that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a small error: when you say that “From (a) we know that $G^c$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed”, that is not correct. The set $G^c$ is *not* the same set mentioned in (a). Of course, you can say that all it takes is to use the same argument.

I would gave solved (a) by observing that $F=f^{-1}\bigl([0,+\infty)\bigr)$, where$$f(x,y)=y-\frac1{1+x^2}$$and I would have solved (b) using a similar approach.